# How to stop ASP automatically changing date type?

Tags: asp-classic

Quick question for an ASP experts out there! I am reading a SQL database using ASP. The fieldtype in SQL is "datetime"  ie.  2012-08-15 08:08:20.140

However when I read this via Classic ASP ADODB RecordSet I get "15/08/2012". This is slightly un-helpful as I would like it to read in in the exact same format as it appears on SQL Server.

Is there any way I can stop ASP changing the date and just read it in as it appears from SQL Server in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform a date-string in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91734/how-to-transform-a-date-string-in-classic-asp)

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate: this one asks about how to avoid an automatic conversion whilst the other asks how to convert the date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of SetLocale and FormatDateTime.

About SetLocale: 
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_setlocale.asp

About FormatDateTime:
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp

Here is an example:

```
SetLocale 4105 ' 4105 => Canada, which is ISO-8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)

SQL = "select user_date from user"
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open Application("ConnectionString")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandText = SQL
Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.CursorLocation = 3
Set rst = cmd.Execute

echo FormatDateTime(rst('user_date').Value,vbShortDate);
```

Comment: Thanks! That gave me the steer in the right direction that I needed :)

Comment: Glad to hear...for future visitors to this page, do you mind posting what you came up with as the solution?